# manage.py runserver 0:8000 with SSL

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, puppet

I am running `manage.py runserver 0:8000` but I would like to display it as HTTPS. I'm using Nginx . I have installed the certificate in the appropriate folders in Nginx. I can see the secured Nginx default page when I browsed to `mywebsite.example` (without port 8000) but I get a blank page when I add port 8000 to it.

I have tried multiple options below but still unable to get `mywebsite.example:8000` to work on a secured SSL page. Any thoughts?

Below are what I have tried so far

1. `manage.py runserver_plus`
2. `manage.py sslserver`
3. All sorts of Django extensions

Comment: Why do you want to use SSL with `manage.py runserver`? That command should only be used in development. And how is Nginx involved?

Comment: As I said on your other question, you should deploy Django properly e.g Nginx + gunicorn. If you encounter a specific problem, then show your config and any errors from the logs. Stack Overflow is not the correct place to ask for a full guide.

Comment: The code I'm running is this https://github.com/ribeiroit/boh-puppet/blob/master/manifests/init.pp . It uses nginx as underlying webserver.